# Multithreading using python bottle framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

New to python and threading, so i'm not sure if threading is happening as mentioned below --

Here, I'm trying to deploy an individual thread for each event. A new thread should be created when user presses "submit button" every time, then execute it.

**a.py file :**

```
from bottle import request, template,route,run,get,post
import sqlite3
import threading
import datetime

@route('/')
def index():
    return template('ins')

@post('/result')
def result():
    # print(request.body.read())  gives raw data
    result = request.forms
    usr_time = request.forms['usr_time']      #get all the values using keys
    A = request.forms.get('A')
    B = request.forms.get('B')
    C = request.forms.get('C')
    usr_hour,usr_mins = usr_time.split(":")


    with sqlite3.connect("database.db") as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()

        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bottable(hour TEXT, minutes TEXT, A TEXT, B TEXT, C TEXT)")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO bottable(hour,minutes,A,B,C) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", (usr_hour,usr_mins,A,B,C))
        cur.execute("select * from bottable")
        data = cur.fetchall()       #get the whole table

        conn.commit()

    t1=threading.Thread(target=calc, args=(data,))    
    t1.start()  

    return template("result",result = result)

def calc(data):

    print(data)               #prints the whole table
    match_not_found=True
    while match_not_found:
        h=datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%H")              
        mi=datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%M")
        # z=[(i[2],i[3],i[4]) for i in data if i[0] == h and i[1]==mi]
        for i in data: 
            if i[0] == h and i[1]==mi:
                print ([j for j in i[2:5] if j != None])
                match_not_found=False
                break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(host='localhost',port=8080,debug='True',reloader='True')
```

**ins.tpl :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="http://localhost:8080/result" method = "POST">
Select a time:
<input type="time" name="usr_time">
<br> <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="A" value="A is on" >A </input>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="B" value="B is on" >B </input>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="C" value="C is on" >C </input>
<br><br>
<input type="submit"> </input>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

**result.tpl:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>

      <table border = 1>
         %for key, value in result.items():

            <tr>
               <th> {{ key }} </th>
               <td> {{ value }} </td>
            </tr>

         %end
      </table>

   </body>
</html>
```

Both ins.tpl and result.tpl are stored in views folder('cause i'm using bottle). I'm not sure if a new thread is generated every time. Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

The code looks like it does indeed kick-off a new thread with every submit.  This is easy to verify using [*threading.enumerate()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.enumerate).

It looks like there is a race condition in *calc()* with multiple threads competing for access to *stdout* via the *print()* function.  You can fix that by combining all output lines into a single string and printing all at once (or better, create a print queue and do the printing in a separate thread).

Comment: Also, there's threading, multiprocessing, queue and then there's also pool. I'm kinda confused what/ where to use these.  Can i get an info as what to learn before i jump into threads/processing?

Comment: @Captainaalooreportin'in Here is a link to a video on approaches to concurrency, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zinZmE3Ogk , and here are the slides, https://pybay.com/site_media/slides/raymond2017-keynote/index.html